# Are there any other settings besides php.ini to allow file upload?

Tags: media

I have a problem with drupal upload file (core module) bigger than 1 MB. For images smaller than this, the upload run smoothly, the progress bar correctly shows the progress and when completed it display the uploaded images as expected.

However, when I tried to upload image bigger than 900 kb, the problem start to arise. The throbber progress indicator show progress until about 98% and then restart again from 0% and never completed and stuck.

In Firebugs it shows that the request was aborted when the progress reach 94%-98% depending on the size images I uploaded. And it only happend when the file > about 900 kB and never for smaller images.

I already changed the php.ini as suggested here and I verified through phpinfo() it is correct setting. I also change the max_input_time and max_execution_time in httpd.conf

In fact, when uploading images, I monitor temporary folder /tmp and it shows temporary file progressing from 0 to the size of the file and restarting from 0 again. Thus, it indeed receive the file, no issue on the size of the file.

I also check the permission, 777 on /tmp and 755 on default/files and it is no problem as I can easily upload 500kb images.

Can anyone help? is there any other settings in the server I have to look into?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please read through this documentation:
https://www.drupal.org/node/97193

Depending on your HTML form and server configuration if you have a 1MB filesize limit; uploaded files *close to your maximum filesize* may not successfully upload to a webserver because a file is sent as apart of a *multi-part* HTTP transmission.

You want to assure post_max_size is typicaly 2x or 3x larger than your upload_max_filesize. Brief discussion on this can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15077229/1491507

Googling PHP maximum post size and file sizes should lead to similar documentation on php.net and other resources.

Comment: thank you @tenken, That's exactly what I followed and I can confirm that in phpinfo() it shows correct setting as suggested. I even try to create small php upload program on http://ping.rustamaji.net/uploadtest.html and i can upload about 4 MB file successfully although the browser shows connection was reset

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I conclude that the problem is not on the server side, but rather on my client and LAN. Apparently using proxy server (I use ClearOS) as gateway server, to access server that is the cause the problem.

By turning off proxy (squid), accessing directly internet, the problem immediately dissapear. But the problem remains if we are behind proxy server.